# Add option price to the final price of the product

Tags: price, custom-options

I have product with custom options.
I want to show the price = regular price + option value

In the price.phtml I have found this:

```
<div class="price-box">
    <?php $_convertedPrice = $_store->roundPrice($_store->convertPrice($_product->getPrice())); ?>
    <?php $_price = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_convertedPrice); ?>
    <?php $_regularPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_convertedPrice, $_simplePricesTax); ?>
    <?php $_finalPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_convertedFinalPrice) ?>
    <?php $_finalPriceInclTax = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_convertedFinalPrice, true) ?>
    <?php $_weeeDisplayType = $_weeeHelper->getPriceDisplayType(); ?>
    <?php if ($_finalPrice >= $_price): ?>
```

Suppose the regular price of the product is 500 and Option value is +50
then in the product page how can i show 550 when the page is loaded (without clicking on the option radio button)

So far I tried this:

> (this works fine in
>   app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php)

```
if ($_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO
            || $_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX
            ) {
             $_productId = $this->getProduct()->getId();
                $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_productId);
                $spl_price=$_product->getFinalPrice();
                if($count==2)
                {
                    $rent=$this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false); 
                }
                else 
                {
                    $buy=$this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false); 
                }
                $total_rent = $rent + $spl_price;

            }
```

> But doesn't work with price.phtml file.

And i tried to pass $total_rent in this:

```
<?php $_finalPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($$total_rent) ?>
```

but I suppose it doesn't work this way here.

**ScreenShot:** Check the first arrow. I want to replace 200 with 700.
[image: .]

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried so far? Have you done some research or debugging on this?

Comment: Sander, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

Use [this](https://github.com/magebuzz/Magebuzz_Customoption) extension and install the respective module in your magento website. Paste into your magento root directory.

Goto **Admin Panel >> Menu >> Product Options**. Select the product and its options which you want to display over the front end.

Please find the attached screenshot for the implementation I have done.
[image]
Let me know incase of any further query/concern regarding the same.

Comment: Dear AddWeb Solution, 
I have added a screenshot. That will make my question much clear now.

Comment: Please check, I have updated my answer with screenshot attached.

Comment: In my case when the option is selected the price gets updated to 700. That's not the issue. I want to show 700 directly even when the option is not selected.

Comment: Have to installed the module? As this modules provides default functionality where you don't have to select any option on frontend.

Comment: No I haven't installed the module yet. I guess I have tried this module before, but I got some error on the frontend. Let me try it once more, I will let you know :)

Comment: Ok I tried this module this works but as you can see in my screenshot, I have customized the options also I have made the custom options to call the addToCart function on click. So I is there any way I can use your extension with  my custom requirements?

Comment: I need to review your code for better insight.